# IE7 Hack for float/block bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having trouble getting this layout to work in IE7:

```
<span class="box">Headline<a href="more">More...</a></span>

.box {
 display: block;
}

.box a {
 display: inline;
 float: right;
}
```

All browsers display it in the right manner;

```
Headline                            More...
```

But IE7 makes this:

```
Headline
                                    More...
```

Any ideas on fixing this? I tried setting the a to block, inline-block, anything, didn't work. Also with some often used fixes like box-model etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put the `<a>` tag at the beginning of the `.box`

```
<span class="box"><a href="more">More...</a>Headline</span>
```

Comment: Oh wow, you are a god! Thanks you so much - too bad I can only give one upvote, you saved me a day full of try and error!